# Hide in Woocommerce Dashboard, for specific User Role 'Order' sub-menu from Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```js
if (!current_user_can('administrator')) {
 function remove_admin_menus () {
     global $menu;
     $removed = array(
         __('WooCommerce'),
         );
     end ($menu);
    while (prev($menu)){
         $value = explode(
                 ' ',
                 $menu[key($menu)][0]);
         if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $removed)){
             unset($menu[key($menu)]);
         }
     }
 }
 }
 add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menus');
```

This code hide the whole Woocommerce item from Wordpress dashboard, if you are Administrator, but i didn't fiind a solution to hide only Orders sub-menu, not the whole item.[image]
Who has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were taking global `$menu` instead `$submenu`. Then you will get a list of all `submenus` registered. You can add the following code. Also it is better to check if user is admin inside the function call

```
 function remove_admin_menus(){
  global $submenu;
  if(current_user_can('administrator')){
    unset($submenu['woocommerce']['1']);
  }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menus');
```

**UPDATE**

Even if the menu is hidden, one can access the page if he knows the url. So inorder to block the access to url, add the following

```
function restrict_woo_submenu_userrole(){
  $current_screen = get_current_screen();
  $p_id = $current_screen->id;
  if($p_id == 'edit-shop_order' && current_user_can('administrator')){
    wp_die('Restricted Access.');
  }
}
add_filter( 'current_screen', 'restrict_woo_submenu_userrole' );
```

Comment: your idea works. But how it is possible to to hide not only page, but in general to restrict the access to the url of this sub menu, because if you know  the url of the page, it will be possible to acces the page even the sub menu is hidden. Do you have an idea to fix this?

Comment: @Asking you are right. Anyone who knows url can access the page. I have updated my answer with fix for that issue. Please see the **UPDATE** section of my answer. Please upvote my answer if this works